# List a remote directory on windows

Tags: python

I try to do a python script which among other things copies the files from a remote windows machine (shared directory) to another place.

In order to list i tried

```
import os
os.listdir("\\MachineX\Projects\EFP\INT\VPM\.")
```

but does not work.

WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '

As well I tried :

```
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('\\MachineX\Projects\EFP\INT\VPM\.'):
    # print path to all subdirectories first.
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        print os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)

    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        print os.path.join(dirname, filename)
```

this one does not return anything...

Any idea is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: did you try `r"\\MachineX\Projects\EFP\INT\VPM\."`? backslashes should be escaped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the `\` which is the problem, it "escapes" the character which follows.  Use a raw string:

```
os.listdir(r"\\MachineX\Projects\EFP\INT\VPM\.")
```

You might also find that a `/` works instead of `\`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this please:

```
import os
os.listdir("\\\\MachineX\\Projects\\EFP\\INT\\VPM\\.")
```